# Code Jam Question: Parent Partnering Returns - Can't seem to figure out what's wrong despite trying many different kinds of test cases

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently trying to learn and get better at Python through these kinds of exercises; the problem I'm trying to solve is a scheduling task, more specifically the [Parent Partnering Returns](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000019fd27/000000000020bdf9) task from Google Code Jam 2020.

My code passes the sample test cases, but outputs the wrong answer when submitted. I've tried to come up with many different kinds of test cases to find the cracks in my code, but none of them have led me to find the inherent issue.

My approach is to sort the list of tasks by increasing start time, then assign them to Jamie or Cameron. If one of them has an existing activity that ends before the start time to be assigned, then the other person will be assigned the activity at hand. If both do, then a valid schedule is impossible.

[Screenshot of Sample taken from Code Jam Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2UZG.png) (my code passes these test cases)

Below is the code I have, any help for finding the issue or a test case that fails would be greatly appreciated:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    T = input()
    for a in range(int(T)):
        N = input()
        orderedSchedule = []
        output = ""
        tasks = []
        JamieEndtime = -1
        CameronEndtime = -1
        for b in range(int(N)):
            line = input() # string input
            singleTask = []
            temp = line.split(" ") # separate numbers
            singleTask.append(temp)
            singleTask = singleTask[0]
            tasks.append(singleTask)

        for x in range(len(tasks)): # convert into integers
            for y in range(len(tasks[0])):
                tasks[x][y] = int(tasks[x][y])

        unsortedTasks = tasks.copy()

        tasks.sort()

        for i in range(len(tasks)):
            if tasks[i][0] < CameronEndtime:
                orderedSchedule.append("J")
                if tasks[i][0] < JamieEndtime:
                    output = "IMPOSSIBLE"
                    break
                else:
                    JamieEndtime = tasks[i][1]
            elif tasks[i][0] < JamieEndtime:
                orderedSchedule.append("C")
                if tasks[i][0] < CameronEndtime:
                    output = "IMPOSSIBLE"
                    break
                else:
                    CameronEndtime = tasks[i][1]
            elif tasks[i][0] >= JamieEndtime and tasks[i][0] >= CameronEndtime: # if no conflict at all
                orderedSchedule.append("C") # assigned to Cameron by default
                CameronEndtime = tasks[i][1]
            if output == "IMPOSSIBLE":
                break

        for j in range(len(tasks)): # output schedule in order of initial input
            if output == "IMPOSSIBLE":
                break
            index = tasks.index(unsortedTasks[j])
            output += orderedSchedule[index]

        print("Case #" + str(a+1) + ": " + output)
```

Comment: Keep your details Crisp and concise. Troubleshoot on where you're getting an error and paste what error you're getting, so that the community can better understand your question.

Comment: What are you entering for all the `input()`s

Comment: The error is wrong answer (or WA if you're familiar with Code Jam), the test cases they use are not visible to me, so I wouldn't know exactly where the error is.

Comment: `input()` is for the test cases to be read in, so lines of numbers. I've attached the link to the screenshot of the sample tests (or original problem as well) above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to break it.  Test case:

```
1
2
1 2
1 2
Case #1: CC
```

It did the assignments successfully, but failed in composing the output string.  The code for retrieving the assignments fails if there are two tasks with the same start and end times.  (The call to the index function always returns the position of the first match.)  The problem statement did not guarantee that the times of all tasks would be unique.

There may be other defects, but this is at least one.

Comment: Thank you so much! This indeed turned out to be the issue, I completely left out the possibility of two identical times when writing the program.